# What is the ideal fitting to reduce gas line diameter from 3/4" to 3/8"?

Tags: plumbing, natural-gas

I purchased a gas dryer that accepts a 3/8" NPT gas fitting at the back (typical of most gas dryers, I assume). My main gas line in the wall is 3/4". Total distance from meter to gas dryer is about 15-20 feet.

Given the ideal gas line configuration, what is the ideal fitting to reduce from 3/4" to 3/8"? Or should this be accomplished with more than one fitting (i.e., one fitting from 3/4" to 1/2" and another fitting from 1/2" to 3/8")?

Here is an insert from the Owner's Manual for the LG DLGX9001V:

[image]

If the dryer takes a 3/8" NPT fitting for the gas supply, and the home has a 3/4" gas supply pipe in the wall, with what fitting should I accomplish the reduction in diameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would run 3/4 black pipe close to the dryer location (within 4 feet).  Then assemble a [Tee](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Mueller-Global-3-4-in-Black-Malleable-Iron-Threaded-Tee-520-604HN/100073073) with fittings to make a sediment trap, a [3/4 to 1/2 inch reducer](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Mueller-Global-3-4-in-x-1-2-in-Black-Malleable-Iron-FPT-x-FPT-Reducing-Coupling-521-343HN/100167004),
[image]

a cutoff valve, and then [this appliance connector](http://www.homedepot.com/p/HOME-FLEX-3-8-in-MIP-x-1-2-in-FIP-x-72-in-Stainless-Steel-Dryer-Connector-HFDC-75-72/204626646).

[image]

A step up in appliance connectors is [this one](http://www.homedepot.com/p/BrassCraft-Safety-PLUS-Gas-Installation-Kit-for-Dryer-and-Range-60-500-BTU-PSC1081-K5/100112627)
[image]
which automatically cuts the flow (to a tiny trickle) if there is grossly excess gas flow as when the hose is disconnected or the appliance fails in some dramatic way.

Some might omit the sediment trap.

Answer (score 0):

For gas pipe you need to use black iron, or black steel not galvanized pipe.
Here is 1 link to [3/4"x 3/8" black iron pipe](https://www.grainger.com/product/GRAINGER-APPROVED-Reducer-1XKT2?functionCode=P2IDP2PCP). Small gas lamps can go as small as 1/4" these are rare here in the U.S. but I have installed them in the past.

Comment: I would put a shutoff valve at the reducing nipple. This is required in my area when flex pipe is used like @wallyk shows this would be the correct way to plumb the gas to the dryer.